# Joining Unrelated Tables in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

Bottom line - I want to join two database tables together that *do not* "belong to" each other but *do* have a common field.

After some research on StackOverflow, I found some solutions to similar problems that use SQL directly, like so:

```
Address.joins('INNER JOIN phones on addresses.person_id = phones.person_id').select("addresses.*, phones.*").limit(1)
```

When I use the above statement in my rails console, however, it performs the following SQL query:

```
Address Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  addresses.*, phones.* FROM `addresses` INNER JOIN phones on addresses.person_id = phones.person_id LIMIT 1
```

and returns the following data (censored for privacy reasons):

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Address id: 0001, created_at: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", updated_at: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", description: nil, line1: "123 Evergreen Terrace", line2: "", line3: "", city: "Springfield", state: "IL", country: "USA", zip: "11111", building_number: "001", person_id: 1, address_type: "Home", primary: false, show: nil, job_id: nil, room_number: "001", source: "HR", effective_date: "YYYY-MM-DD">]>
```

Not a single field from the Phone table made it into the final record.

Do I have to make these unrelated tables "belong to" each other to make them work? Like -

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :address
end
```

Or can I do what I want without modifying my models' relationships?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do with this? Do you want to find all addresses that belong to the same person as the phone does? Or are you looking for all addresses and phone numbers for a singular person?

Comment: My aim is to retrieve a table with address and phone information for one person in each row. e.g. <person_id, address_fields, phone_fields>
Knowing how to do this will be helpful for another query I want to write, too, which involves joining records from three tables that share a person_id.

Comment: So you want multiple rows, with each row containing the `person_id`, the address attributes, and the phone attributes?

Comment: get rid of limit for starters

Comment: Yes. In this case, each Person record corresponds to only one Address record and one Phone record.

Comment: Ok good, but do you want multiple rows?

Comment: Yes. I limited the rows to 1 to illustrate the issue succinctly. I figured it would be preferable to dumping an entire table into the question content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data might not be visible in the query, but the record will respond to those fields that were fetched by the query, meaining if the phone record has a `number` attribute for example, doing a call to `.number` will respond with the fetched number

```
address = Address.joins(....).select('*').first
address.number  # => this will print the phone number of the phone record.
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed to know. Didn't realize the rails console was just hiding the rest of the information. :)

Comment: @NewbieOnRails The console isn't hiding anything. The problem is that `Address#inspect` only knows about columns in the `addresses` table, it doesn't know about any extra columns from the query. The `Address` instance, OTOH, does know about everything else from the query because it uses `method_missing` to create accessor methods based on what's returned from the query.